# android arrays, strings, ints, lists, views and complete confusion

Tags: android, arrays, string, int, seekbar

app have 16 seekbars and app want to be able to save all their values into a new array and reference/add the array in a spinner (item).
then app want to be able to select one of these arrays from the spinner and set the seekbars progress from it seekbar.setprogress(arrayitem).

eyes in head have read many posts in here and cant find something that can fit to my needs or really where to start.
whats the simplest and most efficient appreoach?

```
private SeekBar seekBar1, seekBar2, seekBar3, seekBar4, seekBar5, seekBar6, seekBar7, seekBar8, seekBar9, seekBar10, seekBar11, seekBar12, seekBar13, seekBar14, seekBar15, seekBar16;
private Button saveButton;
private Spinner spinner;
```

Comment: [I (pronoun)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_(pronoun))

Comment: strange bunch on here, -1 cos there was an 'i' used. very helpfull thanks jeeez

Answer (score 1):

```
private SeekBar seekBar1, seekBar2, seekBar3, seekBar4, seekBar5, seekBar6, seekBar7, seekBar8, seekBar9, seekBar10, seekBar11, seekBar12, seekBar13, seekBar14, seekBar15, seekBar16;
```

is a very vey bad practice.

use `private SeekBar seekBar[16]` instead.

initialization (in onCreate of your activity):

```
for(int nIndex=0; nIndex<16; nIndex++)
{
    seekBar[nIndex] = findViewById(Integer.getInteger("R.id.seekBar" + (nIndex+1)); // assuming that u've declared 16 seekbars in ur layout XML named seekBar1 ... to ... seekBar16
}
```

Comment: right thanks, then i can use that method to select each seekbar in turn

Comment: ah it says 'The method findViewById(int) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (String)'

Comment: ok solved that one int x = Integer.getInteger("R.id.seekBar");
      seekBar[nIndex] = (SeekBar) findViewById(x + (nIndex+1));

Answer (score 1):

1.create a 2d array (with 16 integers as columns and the max. number of patterns that are allowed as rows)  and 16 seekbars.

2.call `onProgressChanged()` on each of the spinners and have a static value to count the      number of changes and store the value accordingly(ex: if the the onProgressChanged() is for    the 2nd seekbar and the count is 3 store the value intheArray[1][2]).

3.use the following code to get it into aspinner

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.id.thearray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

4.use the foll. code to put the selected value into a seekbar

```
 for(i=0;i<16;i++){
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                    int pos, long id) {

                  seekbar.setprogress(thearray[pos][i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: but i need to ba able to create several integer arrays. how would i do something like make a 2 dimentional array of thearray. so thearray[1] would be an array of ints.

Comment: please make yourself clear...2 dimentional array of what?.There are 16 spinners and so only 16 integers

Comment: sorry im trying to get my head round what to do, thaught i explained it well enough. i want to save the all 16 seekbars progress into an int array. but i need several int arrays.

Comment: Sorry I couldnt understand..each seekbar gives out one integer and you have 16 of these seekbars so you end up with an array of 16 elements...Now what I dont understand is why you want more arrays.Can you explain?

Comment: im storing 'patterns' in an int array and i need to be able to switch between patterns